Add both 2 element into unordered list in my HTML file
I am currently trying to make a comment section and I can manage to alloe user to input their name and comment and I also completed to make a list, however I can't add both inputed name and comment into list as comment. Can you fix Javascript to add both name and comment into list? I want to fix my favascrpt so I can add my elements "comment "into the list which I added ID called "list".


// JavaScript Document
function titleSubmit() {
  document.querySelector("titleNameinput");
  document.querySelector("message");
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = titleNameinput.value;
}

function CommentSubmit() {
  document.querySelector("CommentSubmitinput");
  document.querySelector("comment");
  document.getElementById("comment").innerHTML = CommentSubmitinput.value;
}

function AddItemsintoList() {
  document.querySelector("list")
  document.querySelector("comment");
  list.append("comment")
}
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 16px;
  min-height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.chattitle {
  font-size: 60px;
}

.container {
  width: min(90%, 1140px);
  margin: 3rem auto;
}

.comment__container {
  position: relative;
}

.comment__container {
  content: "";
  background-color: RGB 165, 165, 165;
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 100%;
  /*as hight as container itself*/
  width: 1px;
  left: -10px;
}

.comment_card {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: .5rem;
  min-width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.comment__card h3,
.comment__card p {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.comment_card-footer {
  display: flex;
  font-size: .85rem;
  opacity: p;
  gap: 30px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

.show-replies {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin: -30px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.headimg {
  line-height: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 125px;
}

.container {
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 85%;
  margin: auto;
  border: #000000;
}

.container2 {
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 99%;
  background: #09B018;
  margin: auto;
  border: #000000;
}

.row {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: #09B04F;
  display: flex;
  gap: 2%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.column {
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 60%;
  background: #02DB69;
  min-height: 125px;
  gap: 5%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.navi {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* Centers the list items horizontally */
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.navi li {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  /* Adjust spacing between items as needed */
}

.commenttext {
  font-size: 20px;
}
<div><img src="ECORUM_Logo(png).png" alt="Logo" class="headimg"></div>

<ul class="navi">
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Events</li>
  <li>Project</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>

<br>

<hr>

<h1 class="chattitle">Test Title</h1>


<br>

<div class="container">
  <div class="comment_container">
    <div class="comment_card">

      <script src="test.js"></script>

      <input id="titleNameinput" type="text" value="SampleTitle" style="height:30px; width:70%;font-size: 20px">

      <br> <br>

      <input id="CommentSubmitinput" type="text" value="Comment" style="height:25px; width:45%;font-size: 16px">

      <br>

      <br>

      <button onClick="CommentSubmit(); titleSubmit()" style="height:30px; width:90px">Comment</button>

      <script>
        myFunction();
      </script>

    </div>
  </div>

  <br>


  <br>

</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="comment_container">
    <div class="comment_card">
      <ul id="list">
        <li>
          <p id="message"></p>
          <p id="comment"></p>
        </li>
        <!--I want to add code to include new items from input into this unordered list to make a comment section without moving a new line><!--->
        <script>
          AddItemsintoList()
        </script>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<br>

<hr>




I can't add both inputed name and comment into list as comment.; what happens when you try? How does the result differ from the expected result? What steps have you taken to debug this?

You need to assign the results of document.querySelector() to a variable. Just writing the function call by itself doesn't do anything useful.

E.g. document.querySelector("titleNameinput"); should be let titleNameinput = document.querySelector("#titleNameinput");

You also need # before the ID in a selector.

Although your code is working because element IDs become global variables.

What is myFunction(); supposed to do? You call it but never define it, so the code snippet gets an immediate error. If it's not relevant to the question, remove it.

To replay eacgh comments, let command and adding "#" somehow doesn't work. I removed myFunction. Can you explain more about document.querySelector() please?

The problem is that you only replaced the strings in the existing #title and #message paragraph elements. What you need to do is to add new elements to #list. One way of doing that is to use .innerHTML and constantly add new string elements. This example shows how you can insert variables into a string using template literals.
Also, it's a bad standard to use on-click on an element. You should use addEventListener.

Also, removed irrelevant HTML code.


document.getElementById("commentBtn").addEventListener("click", addComment);

function addComment() {
  const listElement = document.getElementById("list");
  const titleValue = document.getElementById("titleNameinput").value;
  const commentValue = document.getElementById("CommentSubmitinput").value;
  
  listElement.innerHTML += `
        <li>
          <p class="message">${titleValue}</p>
          <p class="comment">${commentValue}</p>
        </li>
  `
}
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 16px;
  min-height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.chattitle {
  font-size: 60px;
}

.container {
  width: min(90%, 1140px);
  margin: 3rem auto;
}

.comment__container {
  position: relative;
}

.comment__container {
  content: "";
  background-color: RGB 165, 165, 165;
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 100%;
  /*as hight as container itself*/
  width: 1px;
  left: -10px;
}

.comment_card {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: .5rem;
  min-width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.comment__card h3,
.comment__card p {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.comment_card-footer {
  display: flex;
  font-size: .85rem;
  opacity: p;
  gap: 30px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

.show-replies {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin: -30px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.headimg {
  line-height: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 125px;
}

.container {
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 85%;
  margin: auto;
  border: #000000;
}

.container2 {
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 99%;
  background: #09B018;
  margin: auto;
  border: #000000;
}

.row {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: #09B04F;
  display: flex;
  gap: 2%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.column {
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 60%;
  background: #02DB69;
  min-height: 125px;
  gap: 5%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.navi {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* Centers the list items horizontally */
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.navi li {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  /* Adjust spacing between items as needed */
}

.commenttext {
  font-size: 20px;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="comment_container">
    <div class="comment_card">

      <input id="titleNameinput" type="text" value="SampleTitle" style="height:30px; width:70%;font-size: 20px">

      <br><br>

      <input id="CommentSubmitinput" type="text" value="Comment" style="height:25px; width:45%;font-size: 16px">

      <br><br>

      <button id="commentBtn" style="height:30px; width:90px">Comment</button>

    </div>
  </div>

  <br><br>

</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="comment_container">
    <div class="comment_card">
      <ul id="list"></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<br>

<hr>




Somehow in my webbrowser this code doesn't work eveb it worked in this stackoverflow...

Probably because I removed the calls to myFunction() and AddItemsintoList(). Also, this code needs to be in a script tag after the HTML code. Otherwise, it won't find #list.  Check the console for any error messages by hitting F12 and then Esc.
